# Is there any good algorithm to find the nearest power smaller than a given number?

Tags: number-theory, computational-complexity

I am an Undergraduate student and new to algorithmic Number theory. Recently I come to know about the method, when $b=2^k,k\in \mathbb{N}$, of computing $a^b \pmod{c}$ by computing $$((...(a\pmod{c})^2\pmod{c})...)^2 \pmod{c}$$

Now, for any natural number $b$ **(usually big)**, not neceassaryly power of $2$, if we have a good algorithm to compute the best $n$ such that - $(b-n^k)  \text{ is small with smallest } k\in \mathbb{N}$, in another way we need to compute $n$ which has $(b-n^k)+k,$ with $ n,k\in \mathbb{N}$ minimum. Then we can use:$$((...(a\pmod{c})^n\pmod{c})^n)...)^n \pmod{c}$$ to compute our desired number with *minimum* steps.

Note: Good algorithm for finding $n$ such that $(b-n^k)\le (b-p^l)$ for all $p\in \mathbb{N},l\in \mathbb{N}$ is also welcome. Also note that we are dealing with usually big $b$, with $90$ digits in decimal expansion(~$300$ binary digits) say, checking for such $n$ using for loop from $2$ to a number increasing each step by $1$ is not a good way.

Comment: The desired constraints are not yet clear enough. For example, $p=b$, $l=1$ is hard to beat

Comment: We are going to compute $a^b\pmod{c}$, where $b$ is a big number. We can compute $a^{2^k}$ by squaring $a$ only $k$ times, where it will take $b$ many multiplications if we multiply $a$ , $b$-times. If we can find $n^k$ such that it is close enough to $b$ then we can compute $a^b$ by only $k$ steps, so, we need such $n$ which is close enough to $b$. Now, if you set $p=b,l=1$ then as $b$ is big enough we have to multiply $a$, $p$ many times

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you meant but note that for any $b$ you need at most $2k$ multiplications $\pmod c$, with average $3k/2$ multiplications. Hence you need the new method to significantly beat this margin to be worth it, since the problem of finding said $(n,k)$ can be very difficult depending on how small you are searching and how large is $(b,c)$.

Comment: @YongHaoNg Yes, you got my point, as I have mentioned if I limit $b$ upto ~$90$ decimal digits say ,and $c$ is a $5$ or $6$ decimal digit number(small).